# Empty space above link text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to solve weird bug in sub-navigation. There are 3 navigations. First two work well, but the third one behaves really weird. There is empty space (like 20px) above text in every link. But that space already works like a link!! When I try to set fixed height of `<li>` element, text is under the box or covers the border. (screenshot how it looks when I set `.panel li` height to 30px - [http://imgur.com/a/XJqoc](https://imgur.com/a/XJqoc) ) I really don't get it and can't find error in CSS, which should do this. Getting so frustrated about it. I will show you HTML and CSS of this.
I will appreciate every help, thank you!
Fiddle here: https://fiddle.jshell.net/7v7m5uuj/6/ (and there doesn't even `display: block` work properly...)

HTML:

```
  <div id="menu">
            <ul class="main">
      <li><a href="#">MAIN NAV</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">MAIN NAV</a></li>
      <li class="showsub"><a href="#">MAIN NAV</a>
        <div class="subnav">
          <ul class="sub">
            <li><a href="#">SUB NAV</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SUB NAV</a></li>
            <li class="showpanel"><a href="#">SUB NAV</a>
              <div class="subpanel">
                  <ul class="panel">
                    <li><a href="#">SUB SUB NAV</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SUB SUB NAV</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SUB SUB NAV</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SUB SUB NAV</a></li>
                  </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">SUB NAV</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SUB NAV</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SUB NAV</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">MAIN NAV</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">MAIN NAV</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">MAIN NAV</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {width: 100%; height: 60px; display: block; overflow: hidden; background: #a32c61; color: white;}
#menu ul.main {width: auto; height: 60px; list-style: none; margin: 0 auto; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; }
#menu ul.main li {display: inline-block; height: 100%; line-height: 60px;}
#menu ul.main li a {width: 100%; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; text-align: center; height: 100%; text-decoration: none; color: white; transition: 0.5s; display: inline-block;}
#menu ul.main li a:hover {color: white; background: #555555;}
.subnav {display: none; width: 85%; margin: 0 auto; position: absolute; top: 130px; left: 0; right: 0; height: 45px; z-index: 10000; background-color: #262626; color: white; padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;}
.subnav ul.sub {width: auto; height: 45px; list-style: none; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 20px; margin-top: -5px;}
.subnav ul.sub li {display: inline-block; height: 100%;}
.subnav ul.sub li a {width: 100%; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; color: #767676; transition: 0;}
.subnav ul.sub li a:hover {border-bottom: 3px solid #a32c61; background: none !important;}
.showsub:hover .subnav {display: block;}

.subpanel {width: 95%; display: none; position: absolute; top: 47px; left: 0; right: 0; margin: 0 auto; height: auto; min-height: 300px; background-color: rgba(38,38,38,0.85); color: white; padding: 5px 0px; z-index: 99999;}
ul.panel {width: 100%; list-style: none; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 15px; margin: 0 auto;}
.panel li {display: block; width: 150px; background-color: transparent; margin: 0 auto; border: 1px solid white; padding: 0 !important;}
.panel li a {color: white; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; height: auto !important; text-decoration: none; border: 0; padding: 0 !important;}
.panel li a:hover {border: 0 !important;}
.showpanel:hover .subpanel {display: block;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found you haven't close the `div` tags inside the `ui` tags. I update a fiddle here https://fiddle.jshell.net/7v7m5uuj/

You may check if it looks like this.

Comment: didn't help.. but thanks anyway! here is screenshot, how it looks when I set `.panel li` height to 30px. http://imgur.com/a/XJqoc

Comment: Fiddle updated, as you can see, there doesn't even `display:block` in sub sub nav work properly...

Comment: just updated     `.panel li {line-height: 34px !important;}` in CSS. you may check fiddle : https://fiddle.jshell.net/7v7m5uuj/9/

Comment: and to maintain hieght of sub pannel div. remove the `min-hieght:300px; `just like this: https://fiddle.jshell.net/7v7m5uuj/10/

Answer (score 0):

So I've finally solved it! It was taking `line-height: 60px;` from main navigation.